# Use Excel color scale to do gradient with more than 3 points

Tags: excel, gradient

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QI70M.png)
I would like to use Excel color scale to do a conditional formatting on some cells.
    If the cell value < 0 --> cell color is red
    If 0<=cell value <1 -> cell color is a gradient chaging from red to yellow
    If the cell value is 1 --> cell color is yellow
    If 1< cell value is <=2 --> cell color is a gradient changing from yellow to green
    If cell value =2 --> cell color is green
    If 2 cell color is a gradient changing from green to yellow
    If cell color =3 --> cell color is yellow
    If 3< cell value < 4 --> cell color is gradient changing from yellow to red
    If cell value >=4 --> cell color is red

```
I tried using multiple rules in the color scale but it seems the cell only recognize 1 rule at a time. Can someone help me to create this? Thanks!
```

Comment: It does only recognize 1 rule at a time - but in a particular order. Make sure the ordering of your rules applies the one you want for a particular cell.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! But I need to apply multiple rules to each of these cells. Is there anyway that I can ignore the order of the rules?

Comment: I should clarify what I meant - if you have 2 rules that change the highlight colour, it will apply one of them first, and then the other, based on the order they are in in the list of rules. If you have 1 rule which changes highlight and 1 rule which changes the border, both rules can apply. Whenever 2 rules conflict, the latest rule is the one which actually applies.

Comment: So you could have the first rule be ">4 = yellow" and then the second rule could be ">7 = green", and then a cell with 8 would show green, because it's the last rule which applies to the cell.

Comment: I see. for this question specific, how should I define the rules so that they don't conflict with each other? It is easy to do this using formulas to determine how to color the cell, but I want the cell colors to be gradient. It is hard to define the rule..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional formatting color gradient with hard stops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33925935/conditional-formatting-color-gradient-with-hard-stops)

Comment: Thank you very much! All solved!